# Emacs swap row position

Tags: emacs

how can I change the rows position such as the following:

```
This is the first row
And this is the second
```

Into

```
And this is the second
This is the first row
```

?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<kbd>C-x C-t</kbd> -- look in the manual under ['transposition'](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Transpose.html)